# Static initialization order issue in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-initialization

This is another variation of an old theme: The initialization order of
static objects in different translation units is not defined.

Below is a stripped-down example of my particular scenario. The
classes G and F are non-POD types. F depends on G is the sense that to
construct an instance of F you need some number of instances of
G. (For example, F could be some message an application emits, and
instances of G would be components of such messages.)

**G.hpp**

```
#ifndef G_HPP
#define G_HPP

struct G
{
    G() {} // ...
};

inline G operator+(G, G) { return G(); }

#endif
```

**Gs.hpp**

```
#ifndef GS_HPP
#define GS_HPP

#include "G.hpp"

extern const G g1;
extern const G g2;
extern const G g3;
extern const G g4;
extern const G g5;
extern const G g6;
extern const G g7;
extern const G g8;
extern const G g9;

#endif
```

**Gs.cpp**

```
#include "Gs.hpp"

const G g1;
const G g2;
const G g3;
const G g4;
const G g5;
const G g6;
const G g7;
const G g8;
const G g9;
```

**F.hpp**

```
#ifndef F_HPP
#define F_HPP

#include "G.hpp"

struct F
{
    F(G) {} // ...
};

#endif
```

**Fs.hpp**

```
#ifndef FS_HPP
#define FS_HPP

#include "F.hpp"

extern const F f1;
extern const F f2;
extern const F f3;

#endif
```

**Fs.cpp**

```
#include "Fs.hpp"
#include "Gs.hpp"

const F f1(g1 + g2 + g3);
const F f2(g4 + g5 + g6);
const F f3(g7 + g8 + g9);
```

F's constructor takes an argument which is the result of applying
`operator+` to instances of G. Since the instances of both F and G are
global variables, there is not guarantee that the instances of G have
been initialized when the constructor of F needs them.

The particularity here is that there are many Gs and Fs all over the
place, and I would like to keep the syntax as much as possibly close
to the code posted above, while still enforcing the construction of a
G whenever an F needs it.

Comment: Have you noticed your +operator does not actually use arguments? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I just put it in to make the example code compile. But the idea was that operator+ combines its arguments (e.g. parts of an application message) so we can create an F (e.g. the application message) from that combination.

Comment: Yes, but funny thing is your code behavior is guaranteed ;-))).

Comment: I took a stab at a reusable solution to this problem:  https://github.com/wkaras/c-plus-plus-misc/blob/master/ORD_INIT/ord_init.h .

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15 .

Change your global objects into functions which construct the object on first use.

```
// Gs.hpp
const G & g1();

// Gs.cpp
const G & g1() {
  static const G* g1_ptr = new G();
  return *g1_ptr;
}

// Fs.cpp
const F & f1() {
  static const F* f1_ptr = new F(g1() + g2() + g3());
  return *f1_ptr;
}
```

Or if you really can't stand adding the extra `()`s, use some `#define`s to hide them:

```
// Gs.hpp
const G & get_g1();
#define g1 (get_g1())
// Definition of get_g1() like g1() from prev. example
```

Comment: Would be good the get rid of the `gN` function definition boilerplate, as well. The fs don't need to be functions as nothing else static depends on them.

Comment: Yes, the fNs don't need this change to make this example safe.  But I prefer to just protect all global variables in this way so I don't run into another initialization problem all over again when I add or change some other code.

Comment: Instead of having N identical `get_gN` functons, you could use a template: `template <int N> G& get_g() { static G g; return g; }`. You could use these with either a plain `get_g<1>()` or using `#define G1 get_g<1>()`

Answer (score 0):

Keep the extern declarations in the headers. Put all the `fN` and `gN` definitions into a single cpp file in the appropriate order.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have many fs and gs in various libraries, so I cannot put them in a single cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trick similar to the one used to initialize `cin` and friends' filebuffers would work for you?  (Read `<iostream>` carefully.)